# what is difference betwn sqlcommand.parameters.add() and sqlcommand.parameters.addwithvalue()

Tags: sql, ado.net

we can use both the method while passing parameters to sql query ?
then wht is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MSDN article on `AddWithValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) explains the difference between the 2. Within is the explaination on the subtle differences.

> AddWithValue replaces the `SqlParameterCollection.Add` method that takes a String and an Object.
>
> The overload of `Add` that takes a string and an object **was deprecated** because of possible ambiguity with the `SqlParameterCollection.Add` overload that takes a String and a SqlDbType enumeration value where passing an integer with the string could be interpreted as being either the parameter value or the corresponding SqlDbType value.
>
> Use AddWithValue whenever you want to add a parameter by specifying its name and value.

Comment: this means it will not check wht data is been supplied to it. it will give the data directly to query   if the parameter is int and i am supplying it string it will directly take it it will not give any error